# Item click event doesnt works correctly

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

The item click event works only when the list activty is first created. if I leave the activity or close the application, the event no longer works. Only if I reinstall the application. Any help?

```
MY ACTIVITY

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        String[] fields = new String[] {
                "Nome da disciplina",
                "Número de faltas permitidas",
                "Número de faltas cometidas",
                "Hora do término",
                "Dias da semana"
        };

       setListAdapter(new DisciplineFormAdapter(this,fields));

 }




protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long lo){
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, lo);
     Toast.makeText(this, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

MY ADAPTER

```
public DisciplineFormAdapter(Context c, String[] l){
    this.context = c;
    this.fields = l;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

return fields.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

return fields[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

return position;
}

@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String field = fields[position];
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_discipline, null);


    TextView fieldView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.field);
    fieldView.setText(field);

    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value);
    name.setText("value");

    return v;
}
```

MY XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DisciplineActivity" >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/field"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/value" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: when it doesn't work what logcat shows?

Comment: I'm guessing nothing...  at least related to the event firing.

Comment: how i fired the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a listItemAdapter (custom).  Put the event listener into the getView of your adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String field = fields[position];
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_discipline, null);


    TextView fieldView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.field);
    fieldView.setText(field);

    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value);
    name.setText("value");

     v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {       
            ... do something...
        }
    });



return v;
```

}

where v is your view.

If you want to display a toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

you will need to call back to your main ui thread - DO NOT ATTEMPT TO TRY TO UPDATE THE UI FROM THIS BACKGROUND THREAD - YOUR APP WILL CRASH!

Comment: sorry, but i dont know what's code inside onResume() i should write

Comment: @user2383879 I am not sure I understand your question?  Do you mean the background does not fire the click event?  Or, there is some sort of auditory or visual effect that is suppose to occur when the click event fires?